# How can I have pagination and sorting working together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, pagination, ruby-on-rails-5

I have methods that sort and allow users to page through the guestlists in a table. They both work individually but I can't seem to get them to work together - the last one takes preference.

I tried using && and || but the first one will only apply.

```
class GuestlistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_guestlist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  Guests_Size = 5

  def index
  @page = (params[:page] || 0).to_i
  @guestlists = (Guestlist.offset(Guests_Size * @page).limit(Guests_Size)) 
  @guestlists = (Guestlist.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction))
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @guestlists.to_csv }
    format.xls # { send_data @products.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
  end
end
```

Helper for sorting

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
end
end
```

Guestlist.html.erb
Sortings

```
<th scope="col"><%= sortable  "firstname" %></th>
      <th scope="col"><%= sortable  "lastname" %></th>
      <th scope="col"><%= sortable  "email" %></th>
      <th scope="col"><%= sortable  "response" %></th>
      <th scope="col"><%= sortable  "dietary_requirements" %></th>
```

Pagination

```
<ul class="pager">
      <li class="previous <%= @page == 0 ? 'disabled' : '' %>">
          <%= link_to_if @page > 0, "<< Previous", guestlists_path(page: @page - 1) %>
      </li>

      <li class="next">
          <%= link_to "Next >>", guestlists_path(page: @page + 1) %>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

I want users to sort but also be able to display x amount of guests on a page together.

What happens is only one is happening.

Comment: Have you already tried `@guestlists = Guestlist.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).offset(Guests_Size * @page).limit(Guests_Size)` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that providing a string to the `order` method is dangerous when you interpret user provided data. This could lead to SQL-injection. You could change this to `.order(sort_column => sort_direction)`.

Answer (score 0):

The second of these lines

```
@guestlists = (Guestlist.offset(Guests_Size * @page).limit(Guests_Size)) 
@guestlists = (Guestlist.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction))
```

always override the first line.

Just change your code to

```
@guestlists = Guestlist.offset(Guests_Size * @page).limit(Guests_Size)
@guestlists = @guestlist.order(sort_column => sort_direction)
```